# How can one show the following quotient has a limit of $1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

How can one show that the limit of the following is $1$?

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{1-x}-1}{x}=1$$

Comment: Just sum the fractions. Elementary.

Comment: Simplify cancelling $x$ in Numr/Denr. Direct plug in $x=0$ will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition of derivative with

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}\implies f'(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{1-x}-1}{x-0}=f'(0)=1$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{\dfrac{1}{1-x}-1}{x}=\frac{\dfrac{1-(1-x)}{1-x}}{x}=\frac{1}{1-x}\xrightarrow{x\to 0}1$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$
\frac{\frac{1}{1-x}-1}{x}=\frac{\frac{1-(1-x)}{1-x}}{x}=\frac{x}{x(1-x)}=\frac{1}{1-x}.
$$